# getting "Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource. " for a particular route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have just joined a project team, so the project involved has a `/admin` route that keeps giving the error

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
```

yet, if I rename the route to something like `/admi` or any other thing, it just works fine..

```
Route::middleware('web')->prefix('admin')->group(function() {
...
}
```

please what do you think could be wrong with the `/admin` as a route name ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have "admin" directory in the "public" folder.
I got similar problem before. The problem's that the webserver wants to go inside of "public/admin" directory, which is not accessible by Laravel's default .htaccess configuration.

So just try to use different route prefix for your action. Like this:

```
// assume, that you don't have "public/dashboard" directory
Route::middleware('web')->prefix('dashboard')->group(function() {
...
}
```

Otherwise you can leave your route the same, and only change the folder name: "public/dashboard" instead of "public/admin" (not recommended, cuz there might be tracked files by git)

Comment: thanks for this. i just figured out there is a folder named admin in my public folder..